# How change width forms with twitter-bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want a change width form width bootstrap.But when I added

> class: "input-xlarge"

in form helper

```
= f.text_field :title, class: "input-xlarge", placeholder: "Title"
<input type="text" placeholder="Заголовок" name="post[title]" id="post_title" class="input-xlarge">
```

width don't changed

how fix?

Comment: Which Bootstrap version are you using? Kакая версия Вы пользуетесь? :D

Comment: I understand you without russian language) bootstrap 3.3.1

Comment: Answer posted, see it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 3.* dropped the `input-x*` classes for sizing, so use something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control col-md-5" />
```

Or for a full width version use just this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" />
```

---

You can also refer to: **[Bootstrap — CSS — Forms — Control Sizing](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes)**